# Why both Cassandra nodes owns 100.0 %?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am playing with Cassandra, i configured two nodes on two virtual machine, both nodes are clean, number of tokens are 256, nodes detected each other but both owns 100%, what should i do to balance load?

```
Starting NodeTool
Datacenter: 16
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token
UN  172.16.47.183  104.24 KB  100.0%            ace3bddb-dd03-4ab9-88ef-49b99a1289ae  -9170032883711216954
UN  172.16.47.130  128.96 KB  100.0%            a14ee1fd-a993-43a5-9994-183f25de997f  -9181340211822384770
```

Answer (score 10):

That would be expected if your replication factor is 2. Effective ownership for a keyspace should be equal to RF * 100%